# Why does one of this work but not the other - fetch and useState - react/JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, fetch

**I am looking for an explanation as to why the below does not work**

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Genrenavbar() {
  const [mygenres, setMygenres] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function APIrequests() {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_MY_TEST_API}&language=en-US`
      );
      const movie = await response.json();
      console.log(movie);
      setMygenres(movie);
      console.log(mygenres);
    }
    APIrequests();
  }, []);
 
   const help = mygenres.genres.map((elem) => console.log(elem.name));

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**But this one works**

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Genrenavbar() {
   const [mygenres, setMygenres] = useState({ genres: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    async function APIrequests() {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_MY_TEST_API}&language=en-US`
      );
      const movie = await response.json();
      console.log(movie);
      setMygenres(movie);
      console.log(mygenres);
    }
    APIrequests();
  }, []);
 
   const help = mygenres.genres.map((elem) => console.log(elem.name));

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The only difference is the first line being

**const [mygenres, setMygenres] = useState([]);**

change into

**const [mygenres, setMygenres] = useState({ genres: [] });**

On a side note, it also wont work if done like the below

**const [mygenres, setMygenres] = useState([{}]);**

or

**const [mygenres, setMygenres] = useState({});**

The below is the return my API fetch requests gives

```
genres: Array(19)
0: {id: 28, name: 'Action'}
1: {id: 12, name: 'Adventure'}
2: {id: 16, name: 'Animation'}
3: {id: 35, name: 'Comedy'}
4: {id: 80, name: 'Crime'}
5: {id: 99, name: 'Documentary'}
6: {id: 18, name: 'Drama'}
7: {id: 10751, name: 'Family'}
8: {id: 14, name: 'Fantasy'}
9: {id: 36, name: 'History'}
10: {id: 27, name: 'Horror'}
11: {id: 10402, name: 'Music'}
12: {id: 9648, name: 'Mystery'}
13: {id: 10749, name: 'Romance'}
14: {id: 878, name: 'Science Fiction'}
15: {id: 10770, name: 'TV Movie'}
16: {id: 53, name: 'Thriller'}
17: {id: 10752, name: 'War'}
18: {id: 37, name: 'Western'}
```

I don't understand why we need to put **genres** whitch is a key from my response in the state. Does it have something to do with putting a fetch request in a state? When I create a local array of objects outside of the fetch request, I can easily just put the variable holding the array in the state using setState without the need to put the key (from my array of objects) into the state **and my mapping function to map the state will work just fine**.

However, if I do not put a key in the example above, my mapping function will not work on the state (this is despite the fact that I can console.log out the state).

If you are going to say that when I initially map I am mapping an empty array then I don't understand why this would be? Shouldn't the response already be returned (as I am using await for the fetch to be returned) and shouldn't it already be set as the state before the time I begin mapping (as I setState inside my useEffect and starting mapping outside my useEffect)?.

**If someone can quick a description of the order of events that occur with the reasoning why one of these works (and why we NEED to put the key) but the other ones do not work that would be great.**

Thanks.

Comment: `console.log(mygenres);` right after setting will never indicate 'success'.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining the state as just an array:

```
const [mygenres, setMygenres] = useState([]);
```

And then trying to read a property called `genres` on that array:

```
const help = mygenres.genres.map((elem) => console.log(elem.name));
```

Arrays don't have a property called `genres`, so it's `undefined`.  And trying to call `.map()` on `undefined` will produce an error.

Alternatively, when you define an object with a property called `genres`:

```
const [mygenres, setMygenres] = useState({ genres: [] });
```

Then you can read the property `genres` from that object.  And that property is an array, so you can call `.map()` on it:

```
const help = mygenres.genres.map((elem) => console.log(elem.name));
```

Overall the key difference is that if you want an object with a custom named property which is an array, just definining an array by itself doesn't satisfy that.  You need to define the object, with that property.

Comment: But the OP overwrites the state with the response anyway `setMygenres(movie);` so the initial state only has any effect on the initial render

Comment: @pilchard: Indeed.  And the output suggests that the state is being overwritten with an object that has a property called `genres` which is an array.  So the structure will continue to be usable on the next render.

Comment: @pilchard that's true but irrelevant, since that initial render will crash with an error so the user will never see a working UI even after the API request completes

Comment: I understand that @RobinZigmond, but it seems clearer to simply conditionally render on a null initial state

Comment: @pilchard: That I would agree with.  Perhaps conditionally render a "loading" indicator of some kind, even just a simple spinner graphic.  The OP is certainly welcome and encouraged to provide a better UX.  But the root cause of the problem in the question was simply that the OP was trying to call `.map()` on `undefined` because they had the wrong combination of structure and logic.

Comment: oh I wasn't even thinking about the right solution to this (it seems hard to know what the OP wants since `genres` isn't actually used in the rendered output!), but since the question was basically "why does this version not work" (presumably meaning it crashes), this answer gives a sufficient explanation imo

Comment: @pilchard Quick question, when you say its better to conditionally render on a null initial state, do you mean something like this?

const [mygenres, setMygenres] = useState();

Comment: @Codeallday: That would produce an initial state of null, yes.  Then in your component logic you could have some conditional rendering which checks if the value is null(ish) and renders different output.  There are different ways to approach that.  You could also have a separate `isLoading` boolean state value, for example.

Comment: @Robin Do you have any suggestions for structuring my code where I would not have to put in a genres key? Is that been possible?

Comment: @David If I do this  const [mygenres, setMygenres] = useState(); I still get the mapping error. Must i tell the code what to render if it is null (whitch it should not be for long as I am fetching data). Would it not just render nothing or only give me a temp error until my fetch is complete?

Comment: @Codeallday: If that's the **only** change you made then, yes, the call to `mygenres.genres.map()` will still fail, and for the same reason.  There is no property called `genres` on `null`.  The code will do exactly and only what you tell it to do.  If `mygenres` might be `null` then you need to account for that in your logic.  You can't assume it has a value if you know that it might not.  Much in the same way that, in the original question above, you can't assume `mygenres` has a property called `genres` if you know that `mygenres` might just be an array.

Comment: @David Ok I see what you are saying. I was under the impression that once I set the state to a variable which contains property called genres, I can directly map my state after that as my state now 'holds' an array with a property called genres. But that is not the case here. However, If I create a local array with the same info as my fetch then try to map it, I don't have to put in the genres key. Do you know why that is? Is it that my fetch does not update my state in time, causing it to give me an error as it is trying to map a null array?

Comment: @Codeallday: I can't really provide specifics about code I'm not seeing.  But, in general, if you have an array then you can call `.map()` on that array.  It doesn't matter if that array is referenced by its own variable or by a property on an object or by anything else.  You can call `.map()` on an array.  You can't call `.map()` on `undefined` or `null`.  Based on this and the edits to the question, it sounds like you're essentially making random changes to your data structure.  That won't get you far. You need to know and understand the structure of your data in order to use it effectively.

Comment: @David Thanks for the help, i'll look over the code with the comments in mind. Can you upvote my question? I don't feel its worth a -2 (created some good discussion about UX/ and mapping) and I am already on the verge (a new to code as you can probably tell so some basic questions).